# How to edit the search results page in Salesforce?

Tags: search

We want to create a custom button/link on the search results page. If we search for an account and there are no search results, there should be a button/link to the create new account page.

How should we approach this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it. You can add buttons to search results page but **for the button to appear there has to be at least 1 record found**.

The button type would have to be "list view button" and you add it by modifying for example Accounts -> Account Search Layouts -> Search Results.

[image]

This would lead to somehow stupid work process of "*can't find it or it doesn't find what you want? Good, type something you know that exists just so the button shows up...*"

---

Out of the box there are few options:

- use the sidebar "Create new" component (requires Accounts tab to be visible)
- start creating the related thing you want (say Opportunity) and enable quick creation of Account when you click the lookup icon. [This is evil because it bypasses validation rules](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/)!

You could also build your own "search before create" page I guess -  either a real full page or something tiny, suitable to be added as Global Chatter action. You could then call this action from Chatter homepage.

[image]

(Delivery is a custom object from Salesforce1 workshop guides)